# Input in different cells and different worksheets at the same time

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a function in VBA to compile five worksheets simultaneously from the data in the main sheet.

The theme is the management of deliveries in different parts of the year of some products. The cells of the main sheet should contain five numbers, each one indicating the number of products to be delivered on a given day.

Entered the numbers, the function should transcribe the number to the X position in the X sheet, the number to the Y position in the Y sheet, and so on.

The sheets are identical in the sense that the coordinates of the first cell in the general sheet are the same as all the other cells in the other sheets.

Therefore, if you enter, for example, =delivery(1,2,3,4,5) in cell E2, cell E2 on sheet 1 will appear 1, E2 on sheet 2 will appear 2...
Finally, I'm supposed to show the sum of the deliveries specified in that cell
I wrote the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
Public Function Delivery(delivery1 As Integer, delivery2 As Integer, delivery3 As Integer, delivery4 As Integer, delivery5 As Integer)
Set cell = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column)

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Range(cell).Value = delivery1

Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
Range(cell).Value = delivery2

Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate
Range(cell).Value = delivery3

Worksheets("Sheet4").Activate
Range(cell).Value = delivery4

Worksheets("Sheet5").Activate
Range(cell).Value = delivery5

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following codes

```
Sub DistributeData()
Dim Arr As Variant
Dim i As Long, dRow As Long, dColumn As Long

    Arr = Split(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2"), ",")
    
    dRow = ActiveCell.Row
    dColumn = ActiveCell.Column
    
    For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
     Sheets("Sheet" & i + 1).Cells(dRow, dColumn) = Arr(i)
    Next
    
End Sub
```

[image]